# How to pass parameter to javascript dynamically

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, checkbox, parameters

I have a repeater control in my aspx page and in that page i have placed checkbox. When a user checks this box, then i want to redirect to a page. I have written a javaScript too to perform this action as follows:

**js:**

```
function update(eid) {
        window.location("Events.aspx?eid="+eid);
    }
```

**following is method in code behind:**

```
protected void rptEventReminder_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox cbx = e.Item.FindControl("chkComplete") as CheckBox;
        Label lbl = e.Item.FindControl("lblEid") as Label;

        if (cbx != null && lbl !=null)
        {
            Int64 eid = Convert.ToInt64(lbl.Text);
            cbx.Attributes.Add("onclick", "update(eid);");
        }
    }
```

that eid which i am passing as parameter is the unique in database.

**javaScript Error i am getting is:**

> JavaScript runtime error: 'eid' is undefined

Comment: try this: cbx.Attributes.Add("onclick", "update('"+eid+"');");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, You are passing `eid` as hard-coded text to `onclick` handler, Which treats it as JavaScript variable thus you are getting an error

> JavaScript runtime error: 'eid' is undefined

Now, In C# code `eid` is a variable thus you need to pass it as

```
cbx.Attributes.Add("onclick", "update(" + eid +");");
```

Answer (score 0):

I found solution to my question. I made little changes in code behind where i am calling a javaScript as follows:

```
protected void rptEventReminder_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox cbx = e.Item.FindControl("chkComplete") as CheckBox;
    Label lbl = e.Item.FindControl("lblEid") as Label;

    if (cbx != null && lbl !=null)
    {
        Int64 eid = Convert.ToInt64(lbl.Text);
        cbx.Attributes.Add("onclick", "update("+eid+");");
    }
}
```

now its working fine.

Comment: You are missing `+` after `eid`